# I can't get the EnvelopeTabs list

Tags: c#, sdk, docusignapi

We are trying to execute below:
In the program using C # DocuSign API REST version SDK,
You are trying to create an envelope with a template,
At that timing, in the field defined in the template,
I want to fill in values from the program.
(The template contains the field of the signature tag.)

■ Issue 
In order to obtain a list of DocuSign fields,
The API (EnvelopeTabs: list) is issued,
【Coding example】
Tabs tabs = envelopesApi.ListTabs (accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, "1");

Following error has occurs.
By specifying a template, the field list defined in that template
The following error occurred when acquiring.

“  Error converting value 1 to type 'DocuSign.eSign.Model.Number'. Path 'signHereTabs [0] .scaleValue', line 6, position 23.”

■ Specific implementation details
Published from DocuSign

· CoreRecipes.cs
We used the following.

1. At the end of the requestSignatureOnDocumentTest method of CoreRecipes.cs,
   Add the following code to get a list of tabs.
   Tabs tabs = envelopesApi.ListTabs (accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, "1");
2. In the Main method of CoreRecipes.cs,
   // *** TEST 1 - Request Signature (on local document)
   EnvelopeSummary envSummary = recipes.requestSignatureOnDocumentTest ();
   Conducted.

■ Other information
If the signature field does not exist
(Eg Field A, Field B, Field C), you can get the field list,
In the case of
When the signature field exists
(Eg field A, field B, field C, signature field),
An error is returned and it can not be acquired.

Comment: Can you post the raw API request/response you are sending/receiving?  That will help diagnose much faster.  If you're not sure how to get your API logs see this blog post:  https://www.docusign.com/blog/checking-api-logs-like-the-weather/

Answer (score 1):

CoreRecipes.cs (Our Source Code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using DocuSign.eSign.Api;
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client;

namespace TestProj
{
    class CoreRecipes
    {
        // Integrator Key (aka API key) is needed to authenticate your API calls.  This is an application-wide key
        private string INTEGRATOR_KEY = "[INTEGRATOR_KEY]";

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Main()
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CoreRecipes recipes = new CoreRecipes();

            //*** TEST 1 - Request Signature (on local document)            
            EnvelopeSummary envSummary = recipes.requestSignatureOnDocumentTest();

            Console.Read();
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public EnvelopeSummary requestSignatureOnDocumentTest()
        {
            // Enter your DocuSign credentials below.  Note: You only need a DocuSign account to SEND documents,
            // signing is always free and signers do not need an account.
            string username = "[EMAIL]";
            string password = "[PASSWORD]";

            // Enter recipient (signer) name and email address
            string recipientName = "[RECIPIENT_NAME]";
            string recipientEmail = "[RECIPIENT_EMAIL]";

            // the document (file) we want signed
            const string SignTest1File = @"[PATH/TO/DOCUMENT/TEST.PDF]";

            // instantiate api client with appropriate environment (for production change to www.docusign.net/restapi)
            configureApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");

            //===========================================================
            // Step 1: Login()
            //===========================================================

            // call the Login() API which sets the user's baseUrl and returns their accountId
            string accountId = loginApi(username, password);

            //===========================================================
            // Step 2: Signature Request (AKA create & send Envelope)
            //===========================================================

            // Read a file from disk to use as a document.
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(SignTest1File);

            EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Please sign this doc";

            // Add a document to the envelope
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
            doc.Name = "TestFile.pdf";
            doc.DocumentId = "1";

            envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
            envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

            // Add a recipient to sign the documeent
            Signer signer = new Signer();
            signer.Email = recipientEmail;
            signer.Name = recipientName;
            signer.RecipientId = "1";

            // Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
            signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
            SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
            signHere.DocumentId = "1";
            signHere.PageNumber = "1";
            signHere.RecipientId = "1";
            signHere.XPosition = "100";
            signHere.YPosition = "100";
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

            envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);

            // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
            envDef.Status = "sent";

            // |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to creating and sending Envelopes (aka signature requests)
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

            // print the JSON response
            Console.WriteLine("EnvelopeSummary:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelopeSummary));

            // *** I added a code here ***
            Tabs tabs = envelopesApi.ListTabs(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, "1");
            // *** I added a code here ***

            return envelopeSummary;

        } // end requestSignatureTest()

        //**********************************************************************************************************************
        //**********************************************************************************************************************
        //*  HELPER FUNCTIONS
        //**********************************************************************************************************************
        //**********************************************************************************************************************
        public void configureApiClient(string basePath)
        {
            // instantiate a new api client
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);

            // set client in global config so we don't need to pass it to each API object.
            Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public string loginApi(string usr, string pwd)
        {
            // we set the api client in global config when we configured the client 
            ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;
            string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + usr + "\", \"Password\":\"" + pwd + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + INTEGRATOR_KEY + "\"}";
            Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

            // we will retrieve this from the login() results
            string accountId = null;

            // the authentication api uses the apiClient (and X-DocuSign-Authentication header) that are set in Configuration object
            AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

            // find the default account for this user
            foreach (LoginAccount loginAcct in loginInfo.LoginAccounts)
            {
                if (loginAcct.IsDefault == "true")
                {
                    accountId = loginAcct.AccountId;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (accountId == null)
            { // if no default found set to first account
                accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
            }
            return accountId;
        }

    } // end class
} // end namespace
```